# upickle read from scalaJS - upickle.Invalid$Data: String (data: 1)

Tags: scala, scala.js, upickle

From ScalaJS.

```
import upickle.default._
import scala.scalajs.concurrent.JSExecutionContext.Implicits.queue

case class Post(userId: Long, id: Long, title: String, body: String)

@JSExport
def posts() : Future[Seq[Post]] = {
  val txt = """[{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  }]"""

  val p = read[Seq[Post]](txt)

  println(p)

  p

}

pp onFailure {
  case x => println(x)
}
```

println(x) prints: **upickle.Invalid$Data: String (data: 1)**

How to make it work?

Updated / sync up with: https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle-pprint/issues/154

Comment: Hard to be sure without seeing it in action.  Have you tried putting in a println before `posts foreach`?  Are you sure that `posts` isn't empty?

Comment: Let's see the data! Open your browser tools

Comment: no need. I've put all here. see updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm..

> "uPickle serializes Longs as "1" in order to avoid
>   corruption/truncation for large numbers in Scala.js. If they're coming
>   down as JSON Numbers, you need to type them as Ints or Doubles"

Comment: Actually where is this quote from? I just run into the same issue, just want to know the source of this info :)