# upickle: invalid string value during deserialization

Tags: scala, scala.js, upickle

I am quite new in scala.js world so I decided to try it out on some small examples and one of them is quite simple get request with parsing of returning json back into scala entity.

Please find code which does it below:

```
def loadAndDisplayPosts(postsElement: Element) = {
  jQuery.get(
    url = "/posts",
    success = {
      (data: js.Any) =>
        val stringify = JSON.stringify(data)
        console.log(stringify)
        val posts = read[List[Post]](stringify)
        console.log(posts.size)
        posts.map(render).foreach(postsElement.appendChild)
    }
  )
}
```

console.log(stringify) returns the following json:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Some fancy title",
    "content": "some very long string with \"escaped\" characters",
    "tags": [
      "algorithms"
    ],
    "created": 1474606780004
  }
]
```

And when everything comes down to the

```
read[List[Post]](stringify)
```

I get the following exception:

```
upickle.Invalid$Data: String (data: 1474606780004)
```

So the question is: is anything there that is done wrong? Is there some valid reason for such behavior?

Version of library used:

```
"com.lihaoyi" %%% "upickle" % "0.4.1"
```

EDIT:

Adding entity itself:

```
case class Post(title: String,
                  content: String,
                  tags: List[String] = List.empty,
                  created: Long = System.currentTimeMillis())
```

EDIT 2:

The following code produces the same error:

```
val post = Post("Some title", "some \"content\"", List("algorithms"), 1474606780004L)
val json = write[List[Post]](List(post))
```

Thanks in advance for clarification.

Comment: I believe upickle serializes `Long`s as JSON strings. Try calling `write` on the manually instantiated list of posts and compare the output with your `stringify` string.

Comment: As an alternative: can you call `readJs` instead of `read`, passing `data` instead of `stringify`?

Comment: Changing callback signature to data: Js.Value and calling readJs method results this exception: scala.scalajs.runtime.UndefinedBehaviorError: An undefined behavior was detected: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] is not an instance of upickle.Js$Value

Comment: Edited question with write example which does not work too

Comment: Can you post the result of `write`?

Comment: As I explained in EDIT 2, write did not succeed producing the very same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually the correct answer turned out to be here: [upickle read from scalaJS - upickle.Invalid$Data: String (data: 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879109/upickle-read-from-scalajs-upickle-invaliddata-string-data-1?rq=1)

**String** is only partially correct answer. You can also use **Double** (at least you get *free conversion from actual long for free on scala side*).

So I ended up with the following entity which works just fine:

```
case class Post(title: String,
                  content: String,
                  tags: List[String] = List.empty,
                  created: Double = System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Answer (score 0):

uPickle serializes `Long`s as strings in JSON, because JavaScript numbers cannot represent all `Long`s.

Therefore, the `created` field of your object should be the *string* `"1474606780004"`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For me `created` is just a timestamp. Will uPickle be able to handle LocalDateTime from java 8 date/time API for example?

Comment: Also from uPickle web site:

Out of the box, uPickle supports writing and reading the following types:

Boolean, Byte, Char, Short, Int, **Long**, Float, Double.

Why does it happen then that library is not able to work with case class that has `Long` field?

Comment: "uPickle serializes Longs as strings in JSON", - not true. `write[List[Post]](List(post))` produces the same exception so I would better say that it does not work with `Long` type at all.

Comment: should I create separate question regarding issue with `write` in `EDIT 2` of the original question or you will provide explanation in the same thread?

Comment: And also, when I do use jackson library to create json and native js to parse it, somehow I do not get this kind of problem ("JavaScript numbers cannot represent all Longs")